How to plot 2 points per each month, where you have 2 values for the team which will be legend in power bi?



Values
Months
TeamName




0.8
Jan
Team A


0.9
Jan
Team A


0.7
Jan
Team B


0.6
Jan
Team B


0.8
Feb
Team A


0.9
Feb
Team A


0.7
Feb
Team B


0.6
Feb
Team B



I am plotting a line chart graph in Power BI.
My table data is like the above. I want to show all the values per each month per team in a line graph.
For Team A, sicne there are 2 values in Jan and 2 values in Feb. Both of the values should be shown
as 2 markers in jan month and 2 markers in feb month. There should not be any sum or any other aggregate of values.
I attached a sample chart.
Any suggestion will be helpfull
I put the values TeamName in Legend. In X-axis = Months and in Y-axis = Values.
enter image description here

Is this what you want? You can add index column from Power Query and then add a DAX column using MonthLabel = [Months]& " " & [TeamName]. This will add separate values for each month for each team in line chart.

You can do this, but I cannot find any way through the x-axis labels, you should figure that out.
Is this closer to what you want?


Thank you for responding. I have added a screenshot, Could you please refer to the image description?
I am looking for your suggestions.
